# TYPO3 Filecollection, Type "Folder from Storage" - Recursion possible?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

is there a way to get a file list recursively based on one file collection that points to a directory in fileadmin?
Currently I only got it to work with files directly in that directory, not also with files in sub-directories of that directory.

[image: File links]

So instead of setting lots of file collections for each (sub directory)

[image: File collection]

I'd like to set only the "top"level directory (here "Kurs77") and have the files, even from sub directories, displayed.

Reason is, editors may add an unknown amount of (sub)sdirectories, and I'd like to have the files automagically displayed in the file list in the front end -- without the need to create an increasing amount of file collections.

cheers,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

it seems that this is a missing feature. Check out https://forge.typo3.org/issues/61238. It seems that the underlaying API is able to do that.

So one solution would be to use TypoScript to make that work.

Comment: hi Georg, thanks for the issue link, will have a look… Do you think it'll be possible to solve via TS in the current version?

Comment: absolutly. it is for sure possible by using a bit xclassing. i will try to check out to integrate the feature into the core for 8.x

Comment: I checked with tsref, seems that the "recursive" option is not implemented in the TYPO3 6.2.x version (https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/6.2/ContentObjects/Files/) that's in use in this project.
Will push decision makers to upgrade to 7.6.x in March latest, so hopefully then this'll be easier to solve :-)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To give the correct answer now: The recursive option is of course available but it is part of the `sys_file_collection` record.

Answer (score 0):

In TYPO3 9 this is working out of the box. pity is not showing folder as title, but recursive works:

[image: edit file collection]

[image: Recusive option for file collection]